# Is the destructor of a derived class virtual by-default if the base class destructor is virtual?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-destructor

I was recently reading about virtual functions and virtual destructors, and the following question aroused.

For instance, I have the following inheritance chain.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() // note: virtual
    {
        std::cout << "Calling ~Base()\n";
    }
};
 
class Derived: public Base
{
 
public:
 
    ~Derived() 
    {
        std::cout << "Calling ~Derived()\n";
    }
};
```

I read that virtual functions of the base class are implicitly virtual by-default in the derived classes. So, I thought that the same would apply to the destructors.

I would like to know, if the destructor of the derived class is virtual by-default. If not, I would be delighted if you provided some explanation.

Comment: You can also use `~Derived() override { std::cout << "..."; }` to make sure that it is a virtual function (and make it a compile-time error if you forget to make `~Base` virtual)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that the same would apply to the destructors

It does, yes.

> I would like to know, if the destructor of the derived class is virtual by-default

In this example, yes it is.

Once something has been marked `virtual`, all overriding descendants of that something are also `virtual`, whether they state it *explicitly* or not.

So, if a method is `virtual`, all derived methods that override it are also `virtual`.  If a destructor is `virtual`, all derived destructors are also `virtual`.

Comment: One can still avoid virtual dispatch when calling `Derived::~Derived()` if the compiler knows exactly which method to call: 1. It is `final`. 2. The type is `final`. 3. It is called due to array-delete. 4. The exact fully-derived type is known for some other reason.

Comment: About this I think it's relevant this cpp core [guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-non-virtual) (C.35: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and non-virtual)